# Store the result of an sql query into a variable

Tags: sql, vbscript

I would like to know how I could assign the result of an SQL query to a variable.

I have the query below :

```
set userid = Server.CreateObject("adodb.recordset")

user = "SELECT id FROM Users WHERE UserEmail = '" & UserEmail & "'"

userid.Open query,OLSLive,1,3
```

and I would like to assign the result of the query so that I can pass it as a parameter to a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one value is expected to be returned you simply need to read the recordsets 1st value;

```
userid.Open query,OLSLive,1,3
if not userid.eof then 'check for rows
  your_variable = userid.collect(0) 'read 1st column, 1st row
  ...
else 
  'no matching row
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that this is VBScript...

```
userID.Open query,OSLive,1,3

if not userID.eof then
   variableNamedSomething = recordset("id")
else
   ' something else
end if
'... get rid of the connection
 userID.Close
 set userID = nothing
 OSLive.Close
 set OSLive = nothing
```

Comment: Sorry my answer was just like the other... I was typing it while the other one got submitted.  NOTE:... I prefer to use the column names in classic asp ordinals collect(0) makes the readability not as good as collect("id") would be... also don't forget to close your recordset when you are done...